# The import org.springframework.http.ContentCodingType cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, maven, http, spring-mvc

I am trying to import Spring ContentCodingType class in my code.I have included the below dependency in my pom.xml.but still it is not resolving and getting compilation error while doing maven clean install.
    Any one please suggest what is the problem here.

**spring-webmvc - 4.3.3.RELEASE**

Answer (score 3):

You need [Spring for Android](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android), specifically [`spring-android-rest-template`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.android/spring-android-rest-template) because that's where that class lives.